# How to migrate parse exported database?

Tags: android, ios, mongodb, parse-platform, dbmigrate

I have couple of parse database files in JSON format.
I have installed parse open server on aws using elastic beanstalk successfully.
I have gone through lots of tutorials which explains how db migration is done for parse on mongodb from parse dashboard.

But now parse has been shut down. How can migrate my database.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the json files using mongoimport. But the problem is that fields of pointer type are not very compatible. Parse Server stores it in a particular way. Such conversions after applied when you do parse migration as per what parse.com had mentioned in the migration process. But the JSON that you had originally from parse.com when imported, behaves slightly different for Pointer column (may be for geopoints also) and you have to fix it yourself.